# Why am I getting a null reference error when accessing a string property?

Tags: c#

**Update:**  Thank you all very much for the information.  I was struggling with it until I started typing out an update here.  Had to talk it out.  I had code that was pulling from the DB:

```
             potentials[k].Address1 = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Address1"))
                                ? string.Empty // that was reading null...
                                : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Address"));
```

**Original post:**

```
public class PotentialInformation
{
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string Address3 { get; set; }
}

public class PotentialCollection : IEnumerable
{
    private Dictionary<string, PotentialInformation> listOfPotentials = new Dictionary<string, PotentialInformation>();
    public PotentialInformation this[string k]
    {
        get { return listOfPotentials[k]; }
        set { listOfPotentials[k] = value; }
    }

    public void Filter()
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PotentialInformation> a in listOfPotentials)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Addr1 {0} {1}, addr2 {2} {3}, addr3 {4} {5}", 
                a.Value.Address1.ToString(),
                a.Value.Address1.GetType(),
                a.Value.Address2.ToString(),
                a.Value.Address2.GetType(),
                a.Value.Address3.ToString(),
                a.Value.Address3.GetType()
                );
        }
```

The error thrown:
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

In each of the rows cases, there is an entry in Address1, but Addresses2 and 3 are null or empty.

I've tried doing:

```
            if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Value.Address2) == false ) 
            if( String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Value.Address2.ToString()) == false )
```

Something about the way I'm handling the nulls in Address2 and 3 is wrong, but I'm new to C# and having a hard time figuring out what it is.  Thanks.

Comment: Properties of reference types are initialized to `null`, so `Address1`, `Address2`, and `Address3` are `null` unless you have other code that sets values to them.

Comment: You should clarify the question. General, you have NRE because Address1,2,3 can be null.

Comment: So far we know that *something* is null that shouldn't be.  Check your debugger for the exact line where the `System.NullReferenceException` is being thrown.  Even if you get a line number, you may need to test a lot of values for null.  For instance, if it breaks on `a.Value.Address1.ToString()`, you may need to check `a`, `a.Value`, `a.Value.Address1` in the debugger.  Work from left to right until you find what's coming back null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C# there is a difference between an empty `string` and a `null` object reference. A `null` object is an unassigned reference whereas an empty `string` is an assigned object reference to a `string` object which has an empty value (i.e. one is not an object, one is an object but with no value).

Use your constructor to assign `string.Empty` value and your null reference exception will go away as you can call methods on an empty string object but not on a null reference.

Comment: You can also avoid this by using explicit property declarations with private fields. You just need to ensure that your properties and/or underlying private fields are initialized.

Answer (score 2):

string is a  `reference type` and like any reference type if not initialized you will get a `NullReferenceException` if you try to access it try to create a private field  something like this

```
private string _adress1 = string.Empty ;
```

and then you can do  something like this

```
public string Address1 
         { get {return _adress1;} set{ _adress1=value;} }
```

Comment: I'm using an automatic property, so I thought it was automatically initialized?

Comment: Automatic property means the implementation of the getter and setter are automatically supplied (i.e. standard single backing field). You still need to instantiate the fields tho' in your constructor.

Comment: Nope automatic property does not work  for this case

Answer (score 2):

`NullReferenceException` occurs anytime you call a member or method on a `null` object, since the CLR can't handle trying to find member which literally don't exist. This means that `Address2.GetType()` or `Address3.ToString()` will throw the exception if the `Address2` or `Address3` are null.

The best way to fix this is to check whether `Address2`/`Address3` are null before calling any of their member functions - in your second example, the exception is thrown because your second `if` statement doesn't check `Address3`, and the second line is still calling `.ToString()` against `Address2`.

You can also fix this by assigning an empty string to `Address2` and `Address3` in the constructor of `PotentialInformation` - since `string` is a class, the default value is `null` rather than and empty string.